# Swift 4 Position of element programmatically

Tags: swift, popup

I have problem to place grey popUp right on top of screen.
it has x and y = 0.0[image]

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    let dialogheigth:CGFloat = self.view.frame.height;
    let dialogwidth:CGFloat = self.view.frame.width;
    self.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(dialogwidth,dialogheigth);
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate? Which element are you trying to move, the gray box or circle? Where exactly do you want it?

Comment: @JustinMiller I want to move grey box on very top of the screen

Comment: hmm difficult to answer without knowing the layout of your views and view controllers. Can you not just do grayBox.frame.origin.y = 0 ?

Comment: @JustinMiller i fix the problem... but on different way) I will put solution right below!

Answer (score 0):

Guys i use https://github.com/daisuke310vvv/PopupController library as PopUp
my solution was send the **right** ViewController to PopUp

```
let popup = PopupController.create(YourViewController).didShowHandler { popup in
   // Do something
}
.didCloseHandler { _ in
   // Do something
}
```